# Does the client PC need to be whitelisted against the Backend API Management Server?

Tags: api, architecture, firewall

First of all, our application ecosystem lives inside the intranet.

I have this diagram:
[App ecosystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfP7D.png)

Client PC - Google Chrome
Server #1 - React Front-end server where users/clients access from Chrome
Server #2 - API Management API
Server #3 - Data source 1 API
Server #4 - Data source 2 API

Does the client PC also need to be whitelisted against Server #2, for it to access data coming from Servers #3 and #4?

I am getting a 500 error code during an axios call requested by the frontend React when it passes a request to Server #2 (API Management API).

The problem arises during user testing phase, since the PC that the user is using was not initially whitelisted to all of the servers (only to us devs), he/she is also getting a 500 error code when her PC making requests to Server #2 (ERR_NETWORK_NOT_FOUND).

I thought this was weird because Server #1 is making the requests not the client PC itself (since the react front was deployed in Server #1, client PC is only accessing it from the PC through Chrome).

I suppose this is because the client PC is not whitelisted in Server #2. But is the whitelisting necessary?
I thought only Server #1 needs to be whitelisted from Server #2 because Server #1 is making the axios calls?

Your advice is very much appreciated. Thanks!

- Tried making an inbound firewall rule from Server #2 (API Management API) - not working

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that your react front-end is not proxying your API calls through Server #1 like you think it is.  It's pretty easy to check, fire up the chrome inspector (right-click, inspect), go to the network tab, reload your page.   If you see requests to anything but server #1 then you are connecting to that server, and would need to whitelist it (or change your API endpoints and proxy them through your server #1.